# Internal line numbers end before last unended paragraph

Tags: line-numbering

I'm currently working on a project where I want linenumbers to appear for text in a table-environment. Lineo provides the command `\internallinenumbers` for this task. As far as I understood, the normal behavior of lineo should be to wait for a paragraph to be broken into lines and than add the line numbering. The `\internallinenumbers` command does not seem to completely respect this routine, as it stops the linenumbering after the last paragraph of the current page and sets the remaining linenumbers in empty space on the next page. The following minimal example can be used to reproduce the behavior:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{bframe}
\internallinenumbers

\Blindtext

\end{bframe}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered output of the minimal example]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction of `\internallinenumbers` with the `bframe` environment not only screws up the line numbering across page breaks, as the OP shows, but also destroys the framing otherwise supplied by `bframe`, as well.

Rather than trying to fix that interaction of `\internallinenumbers` with `bframe`, I instead started from scratch, and modified the `\makeLineNumber` macro of the `lineno` package to lap vertical bars to the left and right of the text line (the bars are of thickness `2\fboxrule`.

Then I created `FrameLineNo` environment, which starts a new paragraph, places the proper sized and located  horizontal rule across the page, resets the line numbers and begins a `linenumbers` environment (with the modified `\makeLineNumber` described above).  Coming out of `FrameLineNo`, I end the `linenumbers` environment, place the proper sized and located  horizontal rule across the page, and end the paragraph.

In the MWE, I show how the `FrameLineNo` environment properly sets the line numbers across a page break, retains the boxed frame around the environment, and how the horizontal offset of the box is controlled by user parameter `\framesep` and the box thickness by `2\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}
\let\svmakeLineNumber\makeLineNumber
\newenvironment{FrameLineNo}
  {\def\makeLineNumber{\boxit\svmakeLineNumber}%
  \setcounter{linenumber}{1}\par\noindent\Xline[-\dp\strutbox]\begin{linenumbers}}
  {\end{linenumbers}\leavevmode\Xline[\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-2\fboxrule\relax]\par}
\def\boxit{\fboxsep=0pt\relax\llap{\fbox{\strut}\kern\framesep}%
  \hspace{\textwidth}\rlap{\kern\framesep\fbox{\strut}}}
\newcommand\Xline[1][0pt]{%
  \llap{\rule[#1]{\dimexpr\framesep+2\fboxrule\relax}{2\fboxrule}}%
  \rule[#1]{\textwidth}{2\fboxrule}%
  \rlap{\rule[#1]{\dimexpr\framesep+2\fboxrule\relax}{2\fboxrule}}\par
}
\def\framesep{.7ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{FrameLineNo}
\Blindtext
\end{FrameLineNo}
\lipsum[3-4]
\def\framesep{.5ex}
\fboxrule=1.5pt
\begin{FrameLineNo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{FrameLineNo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]